# Include the category name/subcategory name and the tag name inside the search query wordpress/php

Tags: wordpress, search, tags, include, categories

I need your help with the search query in wordpress. I need to extend it to be able to search inside the category name, and tag name.

I have to tell the search function to search only inside the:

- post
- title
- description
- inside the category tags
- inside the tags that the question is having

Currently the search function is searching:

- post
- title
- description

and I don't know why it is not searching and is not returning the category that the question is and the question tags.

For example, if I will look for "installment loan USDA dti" I want to get the question as a result.

- USDA - is the category that the question belongs to
- dti - is one of the tags that the question is having.

If I type in the search USDA I should receive all the questions that are in USDA category.
If I type dti I should receive all the questions that have a dti tag.
If I type "installment loan USDA dti" I should get the question that has the installment loan keyword, USDA category, and dti tag.

I  was testing today what is on this link:
http://vzurczak.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/extend-the-default-wordpress-search/
That function is working good, but is limited to searching only the tags and keywords.

1. That code is not searching inside categories.
2. If I type borrower's in search result is not returning anything. But if I don't have that code I am getting the question that has borrower's in the content. I think the code is buggy a little because it is not able to search for the apostrophe sign.
   I don't know if that code will help or not. The file I had to change was function.php from the template file.

I also tried the "search everything" plugin, but it is not working.

Comment: I hope this help, check this [link][1] 


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14241/search-form-with-category-and-sub-category